# Как разделить IT проект?

Tags: веб-программирование, юридические-аспекты, проекты

Классическая популярная ситуация:

От 2-ух до 5-ти разработчиков, которые совместно делают IT проект.

Задач много, каждый выполняет какую хочет/может, т.е. кто-то больше вкладывается в идею и фичлист, кто-то в код, кто-то в раскрутку.
То есть вклад времени, работы и эффективности неравномерный.

Вопрос - как разделить доли от дохода проекта?

- Возможно всё организовывать через системы управления задачами (пример RedMine) и вычислять по затраченному времени или строкам кода через GIT? Но как тогда быть с эффективностью/не эффективностью затраченного времени одним в перевес другого?
- Возможно строго фиксированная % доля каждому? Но как избежать бездействия или не эффективного действий отдельных участников, потому что такой подход сразу подразумевает что кто-то "расслабит булки" и потом будет требовать долю за "просто так".

Должны же быть грамотные оптимальные решения как распределить(ять) доли от проекта. И лучше что бы это можно было юридически заверить, а то как известно, особенно по опыту таких гигантов как facebook, что в серьезном деле рано или поздно любые дружеские и родственные связи могут быть нарушены и тем самым поставлены под угрозу.

Хотелось бы услышать мнения и варианты решения, и особенно из личного опыта. Может быть есть готовые схемы, который я не нашел через поисковые системы.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вопрос финансового и юридического характера, но не в области программирования.

Comment: @Nick, я бы с Вами согласился, и этот вопрос действительно касается не программирования (с чего вы вообще это взяли?), а разработки. И да, немного больше финансового и юридического характера. Но всё же **разработки**, то есть IT проекта и только оного.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак не посчитать. Ибо все входные данные - есть абстрактные и несравнимые величины.

Вопрос напомнил мне мой стартап, который мы начинали делать в Германии в 2012 году. Тоже втроем. Не говоря уж о том, что меня тоже зовут Всеволод ))

В итоге, я несколько месяцев смотрел на такую "работу" и потом плюнул на все и выкупил доли у своих "партнёров". Сейчас имею работающий бизнес, основанный целиком на собственных достижениях. Потому что гениальность фразы *хочешь чтобы было хорошо - сделай это САМ* никто не отменял.

Но я ни в коем случае не хочу проецироваать свой опыт создания стартапа "с друзьями" на ваш. Просто у меня вот так получилось. Но это совсем не значит, что и у вас так будет.

Свой опыт работы с партнерами я сравниваю с легендарной басней Крылова. Когда каждый владел какой-то экспертизой и стремился ее превознести. При этом качественные основы таких компетенций были диспропорциональными и совершенно несравнимыми. Один писал код в поте лица, сидел ночами в глубокой отладке, создавая Продукт; второй тусовался на пляже и в имейлах с телефона назначал конфколлы для обсуждения фиг знает чего)) А третий ставил в облако SharePoint и пытался прикрутить к нему Jira. Потому что нашему, млеать, "бизнесу" надо было трэкать активности и публиковать достижения на портале! :-) Ну как-то так вобщем. Примеров много у меня...

Как вы понимаете, в отличии от задач, которые можно и нужно формализовать, объем вклада каждого вы не сможете формализовать и оценить. Потому что каждый будет настаивать на приоритетности своих идей и важности собственного вклада. Потом начнутся лёкгие недопонимания, подковерные игры, объединения "2-против-1" и прочие "прелести" мелкого и незрелого бизнеса.